# How to generate XML Log file from SQL Server

Tags: mysql, xml

How to generate XML Log file from SQL server?
Example if I am doing any changes in XML file the log file needs to be generate from SQL Server.

Comment: I think you want sql which is mdf (not mysql which is sdf).  The SQL has a transaction log that you can query like any database : Select * from ::fn_dblog(null,null).  See : https://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server or MySQL? Please tag correctly, they are not the same.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio..